# When to use multiple KieBases vs multiple KieSessions?

Tags: drools

I know that one can utilize multiple KieBases and multiple KieSessions, but I don't understand under what scenarios one would use one approach vs the other (I am having some trouble in general understanding the definitions and relationships between KieContainer, KieBase, KieModule, and KieSession). Can someone clarify this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use multiple KieBases when you have multiple sets of rules doing different things.

KieSessions are the actual session for rule execution -- that is, they hold your data and some metadata and are what actually executes the rules.

---

Let's say I have an application for a school. One part of my application monitors students' attendance. The other part of my application tracks their grades. I have a set of rules which decides if students are truant and we need to talk to their parents. I have a completely unrelated set of rules which determines whether a student is having trouble academically and needs to be put on probation/a performance plan.

These rules have nothing to do with one another. They have completely separate concerns, different rule inputs, and are triggered in different parts of the application. The part of the application that is tracking attendance doesn't need to trigger the rules that monitor student performance.

For this application, I would have two different KieBases: one for attendance, and one for academics. When I need to fire the rules, I fire one or the other -- there is no use case for firing both at the same time.

---

The KieSession is the runtime for when we fire those rules. We add to it the data we need to trigger the rules, and it also tracks some other metadata that's really not relevant to this discussion. When firing the academics rules, I would be adding to it the student's grades, their classes, and maybe some information about the student (eg the grade level, whether they're an "honors" student, tec.). For the attendance rules, we would need the student information, plus historical tardiness/absence records. Those distinct pieces of data get added to the sessions.

When we decide to fire rules, we first get the appropriate KieBase -- academics or attendance. Then we get a session for that rule set, populate the data, and fire it. We technically "execute" the session, not the rules (and definitely not the rule base.) The rule base is just the collection of the rules; the session is how we actually execute it.

There are two kinds of sessions -- stateful and stateless. As their names imply, they differ with how data is stored and tracked. In most cases, people use stateful sessions because they want their rules to do iterative work on the inputs. You can read more about the specific differences in the [documentation](https://docs.drools.org/latestFinal/drools-docs/html_single/#kie-sessions-con_decision-engine).

For low-volume applications, there's generally little need to reuse your KieSessions. Create, use, and dispose of them as needed. There is, however, some inherent overhead in this process, so there comes a point in which reuse does become something that you should consider. The documentation discusses the solution provided out-of-the box for Drools, which is session pooling.

(When trying to wrap your head around this, I like to use an analogy of databases. A session is like a JDBC connection: for small applications you can create them, use them, then close them as you need them. But as you scale you'll quickly find that you need to look into connection pooling to minimize this overhead. In this particular analogy, the rule base would be the database that the rules are executing against -- not the tables!)